Can't remove event listener in React despite utilizing the useCallback hook
In my react app I prevent default touchmove behavior, but I'm unable to restore it.
I made sure to utilize the useCallback hook. I have confirmed through debugging that the removeEventListener method is called by the app, but it doesn't do it's job. Using getEventListeners(document) in the dev console confirms the listener is still there.
const preventDefaultTouchMove = useCallback((event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (updatingLock) {
    document.addEventListener(
      'touchmove',
      preventDefaultTouchMove,
      { passive: false }
    );

  } else {
    document.removeEventListener(
      'touchmove',
      preventDefaultTouchMove,
      { passive: false }
    );
  }
  
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener(
      'touchmove',
      preventDefaultTouchMove,
      { passive: false }
    );
  };
}, [updatingLock, preventDefaultTouchMove]);


Try adding event.stopPropagation()

Unfortunately that didn't fix it.

The useCallback isn't really required. Just declare const preventDefaultTouchMove  = (event) => event.preventDefault() at the top of useEffect cb. That said, I don't think it's solving the issue, but you can it reduces the complexity and might be a shot anyway.

This question is similar to: How to prevent default handling of touch events?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Henry Woody That question isn't concerned with removing the event listener, in fact, the removeEventListener method is not mentioned a single time in that question. I don't understand how I can make it clearer that my question is different when there is literally nothing similar about our questions. At the beginning of my question I say "In my react app I prevent default touchmove behavior" which means I've arleady solved the problem of the other user, who asked "How to prevent default handling of touch events?"

@NotX Yes, I've arleady attempted putting the function inside useEffect without the useCallback hook. And I'm not certain the hook isn't required, I've referenced this question link

since you said you confirmed that removeEventListener is being called, can you also confirm that it is the one in the body of your useEffect and not the one in the returned callback?
i agree: this is not at all related to the question Henry mentioned.  i would like to know the answer to this as well.

it's working for me.  i have copied your code exactly, but targeting 'contextmenu' instead of 'touchmove'.  can we see some code that manages updatingLock?  is it just a state variable?

@mulemule useCallback isn't required if you declare the method inside of useEffect, b/c it will remain the same for the scope of this useEffect invocation. I'ld drop useCallback here, even if it's not related to your issue.

I don't see any issue in the code you have shared here. Nothing that would indicate a resource leak. Is this problem still manifesting now? What if you did a complete reboot, i.e. kill the server and close/open the browser and restart the app? I suspect the issue is elsewhere in your code, can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] in a stack snippet? If possible, maybe also a running CodeSandbox demo the reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?
